# What is wrong with my statement

Tags: php, forms, file-upload

When i submit my form and it gets and error: There error message "post was not added". It will then go into a loop and just keep printing.

Can you see the error:

It is really annoying and almost grash my fresh every time.

```
  <?php 
              $q = "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE id = $id";
              $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

              while($vote_list = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) { ?>

      <?php 

                if(isset($_POST['submitted']) == 1) {

                $ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;  //1

                $storeFolder = '../uploads';   //2

                $text = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['text']);
                $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                $uploadfile_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
                $newname = time();
                $rand = rand(100,999);
                $name = $newname.$rand.'.'.$ext;
                //if($_POST['id'] != '')


                if(($uploadfile_type !='image/jpeg') && ($uploadfile_type !='image/png')){  
                   echo "Post was not added!";  

                }else{
                    echo "Post was added!";             
                    $q = "INSERT INTO votes (user_id, text, image) VALUES ('$vote_list[user_id]', '$text', '$name')";

                }
                $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);



                if (!empty($_FILES)) {

                        $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];          //3             

                        $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds;  //4

                        $targetFile =  $targetPath. $name;  //5

                        move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile); //6

                }



            }

        ?>
  <?php } ?>
```

Comment: 1. We don't see your form 2. How can it go into a loop when there is no loop?

Comment: `$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));` now you can get the *real* error and tell us what it is. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the following lines:

```
}else{
    echo "Post was added!";             
    $q = "INSERT INTO votes (user_id, text, image) VALUES ('$vote_list[user_id]', '$text', '$name')";
}
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
```

your `mysqli_query` should be inside else statement, something like this:

```
}else{
    echo "Post was added!";             
    $q = "INSERT INTO votes (user_id, text, image) VALUES ('$vote_list[user_id]', '$text', '$name')";
    $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
}
```

In your code, the value of `$r` was getting reset each time inside the loop and hence it was turning out to be infinite loop.

Comment: Your a genius!!  Thank you.